Most general definition of a geodesic including non-metric spaces and non-affine connections?
Influenced by General Relativity, I originally thought geodesics were only defined on metric spaces. But I realized later that the definition is more general and does not require a metrizable space. Apparently, to define a geodesics one need only two things:

A differentiable manifold
A connection defined on that manifold

Question 1: Is that really all you need? Can geodesics be defined on something more general than that (non-differentiable manifolds?)
Question 2: Is smoothness required also, or (potentially non-infinite) differentiability is enough?
Question 3: Can it be any connection? Including for example Connes connection in non-commutative geometry? Or does it have to be an affine or a Cartan connection?
Question 4: In the case where geodesics can be built from any connection, what is the most general equation they arise from? What is the equivalent of the usual:
$$\frac{d^2\gamma^\lambda }{dt^2} + \Gamma^{\lambda}_{\mu \nu }\frac{d\gamma^\mu }{dt}\frac{d\gamma^\nu }{dt} = 0$$
in the most general case (when we just know that we have a differentiable manifold with an arbitrary connection).
Question 5: Are Christoffel symbols defined for any arbitrary connection? Or they are only defined for metric spaces?
Question 6: In the case Christoffel symbols are also defined for non-metric spaces, can they be computed from something more fundamental that is defined on the manifold, or they need to be given.
Question 7: Would you have good references on geodesics in the most abstract sense (textbooks or maths papers)? Ideally, I am looking for a reference that would start from the most general case (differentiable manifold with connection), and add structure little by little progressively build the geodesics that are the most well-known (metric spaces/affine connections).

I hope you realize that you’re using the terms “metric space” and “metrizable space” not in the standard way (see this question and answer).

You are supposed to ask just one question in a post. You asked 7.

@MoisheKohan I can split them if necessary. It kept them together because I see them as subquestions of the more general question of "How to define a geodesic in the most abstract and general sense?"

There are two areas of geometry which use the word "geodesic", one is metric geometry (no smoothness assumed) and the other is differential geometry. You are mixing the two in your post. Start by clearing up this conflation.

@MoisheKohan Do at least the definitions match for pseudo-Riemannian manifolds?

Not even close.

There are two useful properties that geodesics have: (1) they are the curves of extreme (or at least stable) length connecting two points (2) they are curves that do not change direction. The first requires some means of defining the length of a curve, which is normally done by a metric. The second requires a concept of directions each point, and some means of comparing directions at different points along the curve, which is normally done by a connection on differentiable manifold, defining parallel transport along the curve.

While this doesn't answer everything you have asked, it should give you some useful intuitions. Consider a parametrized surface embedded in some Euclidean space thusly;
$$\vec{R}(x(s))$$
Where $x^i$ are the ambient coordinates and $s^{\mu}$ are the coordinates on the surface. Now introduce a curve on the embedded surface parametrized by $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. The tangent space of the curve at each point will then be given by;
$$\textbf{u}=\frac{d}{d\lambda}\vec{R}(x(s(\lambda)))=\frac{ds^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\cdot\partial_{\mu}\vec{R}=u^{\mu}e_{\mu}$$
Now consider the total derivative of this vector with respect to $\lambda$, that is;
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\textbf{u}=\frac{du^{\mu}}{d\lambda}e_{\mu}+u^{\mu}\frac{de_{\mu}}{d\lambda}$$
$$=\frac{d^2s^{\mu}}{d\lambda^2}e_{\mu}+\frac{ds^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{ds^{\nu}}{d\lambda}\bigg(\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\alpha}e_{\alpha}+B_{\mu\nu}\vec{n}\bigg)$$
Doing some re-arranging then yields;
$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\textbf{u}=\bigg(\frac{d^2s^{\mu}}{d\lambda^2}+\frac{ds^{\alpha}}{d\lambda}\frac{ds^{\nu}}{d\lambda}\Gamma_{\alpha\nu}^{\mu}\bigg)e_{\mu}+\frac{ds^{\mu}}{d\lambda}\frac{ds^{\nu}}{d\lambda}B_{\mu\nu}\vec{n}$$
Where $B_{\mu\nu}$ is the Second Fundamental Form of your parametrized surface and $\vec{n}$ is the unit normal of that same surface. What this expression tells us is that the change in our tangent vector field along our curve can be decomposed into some component which is tangent to our surface and a component which is normal to our surface. Therefore, our curve may not be "straight" in the overall ambient Euclidean space due to the curvature of the surface but may be considered "straight" with respect to our embedded surface by having the following hold;
$$\bigg(\frac{d^2s^{\mu}}{d\lambda^2}+\frac{ds^{\alpha}}{d\lambda}\frac{ds^{\nu}}{d\lambda}\Gamma_{\alpha\nu}^{\mu}\bigg)e_{\mu}=\nabla_{\textbf{u}}\textbf{u}=0$$
Note that, for this specific example which utilized a Euclidean embedding, I have assumed the Levi-Civita Connection but have assumed nothing about a surface metric. That is, we could just as easily have;
$$\nabla_{\textbf{u}}\textbf{u}=0$$
For any general Koszul connection on our manifold.
If we then equip our manifold with an arbitrary metric the Levi-Civita connection would ensure that that the "straight" curves on our manifold coincide with the curves which are the extremals of the length functional. However, for a general Koszul connection there may be no coincidence between the "shortest" curves and the "straightest" curves on a given manifold.
